# identifying next entry

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently working on some portfolio analyses and want to identify the yearly growth rate of new clients and repeated clients, but I could not find a way to do so.

As you can see in the table below, I have repeated clients and also new clients, the question is, how to identfy them?

Let's say I want to identify new client for 2013, if you look into 2013 column  = a,c,e,x and x2 are the client for 2013 but how ever only C is the new client. The rest of the clients are repeated clients. What I was doing to identify new client is putting this table into Pivot and identifying yearly by comparing 2 years but I want to know faster way to do so.

[image]

Comment: What you're asking is not at all clear. Is x2 a "repeated" client, with a different Client name than x? If so, are you saying that repeated clients must be identified by the years they were active, rather than by name? As for new clients, it seems like they sould be active only in the latest year. There aren't any of those.  Please EDIT your question and *clearly* explain what you're trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry for the explanation. Let me make it more clear. Let's say I want to identify new client for 2013, if you look into 2013 column  = a,c,e,x and x2 are the client for 2013 but how ever only C is the new client. The rest of the clients are repeated clients. What I was doing is putting this table into Pivot and identifying yearly by comparing 2 years but I want to know faster way to do so.

Comment: Would you consider b to be a new client in 2014 and 2016, or only when they first appeared in 2012?

Comment: well, it will be repeated client because I do already have billing for that client. It does not matter whether it is first appeared in 2012, once it has already appeared in a particular year, and do not repeat, then I will assume that client is new client compare to previous year.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then the only new clients after 2012 are c (in 2013), d (in 2014) and g (in 2014). Is that right?